# Large dataset in memory - .NET Framework and C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, memory-management, singleton

I have a DLL project that makes a singleton of all the display strings used in my application. The problem is I need a reference of this DLL in many independently running applications.

I understand that if I reference the DLL project in all the independently running applications they will all load the DLL into memory and make individual singletons to which they can refer, but this is redundancy I want to avoid.

Is there a way I can keep one instance of this singleton in the memory and reference it from all the independent projects?

I understand I may be sounding stupid and that this loading may not be happening at all, but I've been searching since about an hour now :)

I am using the .NET framework with C# as the target language.

Comment: This might not be what you need but I suggest you take a look at it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439787/how-to-implement-shared-memory-in-net

Comment: How many applications you have and how much memory does the strings of single application consume?

Comment: @mgronber: Right now it's about 7000 strings and 8 different applications but it's bound to grow uncontrollably in the future.

Comment: Why the number of strings is bound to grow uncontrollably? Are the strings singletons so that they can be easily referred from code?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to embedd the strings in the resources of the dll? Then your static class providing access just looks them up in the resources.

Comment: The string constants are most likely are interned anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not trouble myself with the memory consumption until it is really a problem. We can do some simple math: 2^13 (8192) strings in 2^3 (8) applications is 2^16 strings and if one string has average size of 2^8 (256) chars, the total number of bytes for all applications is `2 * 2^24` (32 MiB). That should not pose any problems even if the number of strings will be multiplied by 10.

The amount of work required by other solutions will make them infeasible at current stage. Also there will be no benefits of common string service, if most of the shared strings are used by all applications. It provides benefits only if a small portion of the strings are really shared by them all.

With remoting you will have to make sure that the singleton instance is initialized only in one place and you have to access it through interfaces. Most likely you want to create a local singleton instance that queries the strings from the remote instance. This solution can also be implemented afterwards if you keep using the old singleton implementation until other solutions are necessary.

If you use taskmanager to track memory usage, you should have a very big string in the singleton class.

```
public static Strings {
    private readonly string MemoryUsageTest;

    static Strings() {
#if DEBUG
        int size = 104000000;
        var text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var sb = new StringBuilder(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size / text.Length; ++i) {
            sb.Append(text);
        }

        MemoryUsageTest = sb.ToString();
#endif
    }
}
```

I am not so sure that remoting would be a good alternative at any point. Anyway, if we assume that it would be a good alternative, I would suggest that the current implementation should use a singleton class that implements an interface. This will make the use of remote instance much easier.

```
public interface IStrings {
    string HelloWorld { get; }
}

public sealed class LocalStringService : IStrings {
    internal LocalStringService() { }

    string IStrings.HelloWorld {
        get { return "Hello World!"; }
    }
}

public static class StringService {
    private static readonly IStrings SingletonInstance = new LocalStringService();

    // If empty static constructor does not make any sense, read this:
    // http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx
    static StringService() { }

    public static IStrings Instance {
        get { return SingletonInstance; }
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to make this remote, you will only need to rename `LocalStringService` to `RemoteStringService`, make it inherit `MarshalByRefObj` and change `StringService` to create a remote instance of it. In addition, the `RemoteStringService` should be in another assembly so that it is not loaded into memory with other classes.

Still, I doubt that this would give you any benefits in this case.

Comment: The math you suggest makes sense and I can hardly argue with it. Additionally the server where these solutions are running is loaded with 8gigs of RAM so my problem certainly isn't a blocking problem right now. I was just looking for a preemptive solution so it was clean from the get go. I now know a solution to this (ie, remoting) if things get out of hand but I think i'll choose to do nothing as of right now :)

Comment: If it does become a problem, I'd recommend C# over .NET remoting

Answer (score 5):

Generally, different processes have different address spaces.  Since a DLL file is usually loaded into a process address space it is necessary to write some special code to implement data sharing between processes.  Usually, this is done using the [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API), for example, with the help of memory mapped files.  You can learn more about this at:

[Sharing memory between two processes (C, Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200998/sharing-memory-between-two-processes-c-windows)

Using the Windows API is not bad, but it somehow contradicts the .NET Framework philosophy.  I think it is better to create a client-server architecture when a single server can work with different clients and pass the required data to them.  This can be done using, for example, [Remoting](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx&ei=3kGQTe-THMrJhAe-2eG7Dg&usg=AFQjCNFiV2algYmPJO_Av8OOzuss36bX3Q&sig2=nbdY4ejfLBzNlatWs1OOoA) or [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx).

Comment: I agree with the point of view, because different processes cannot share the memory directly.

Comment: used remoting and passed a proxy copy around the block. Thanks!

Comment: @Zulfi Tapia: Did you save any memory? Did you use an interface for the object that you passed around?

Comment: @mgronber: I used http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Net_Remoting.aspx for implementation. Memory is kinda the same though. Maybe the strings were getting interned... I am using a crude form of memory measurement, using task manager :)

Answer (score 1):

The string constants used are most likely interned. Call the string.IsInterned static function to see for a particular string. If that's the case, they are not taking excess memory, since every string is in CLR intern pool.

[IsInterned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Make a service wrapper on this DLL file, and call the service from other applications instead.