# Logging from library with spdlog

Tags: c++, spdlog

I am trying to use [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) in a project involving a library under windows.
I create two loggers. One for the app using the library, one for the library itself.
The library's logger is created from the app but when the library want to add a message, it crash.

Following is an simplified example.

**The library**

*libclass.h*

```
#ifndef LIBCLASS_H
#define LIBCLASS_H

#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#  ifdef BUILD_APPLIB_SHARED
#    define APPLIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define APPLIB_EXPORT
#  endif //BUILD_APPLIB_SHARED
#else
#  define APPLIB_EXPORT
#endif // WIN32

class APPLIB_EXPORT LibClass
{
public:
    LibClass();
    ~LibClass();

    static std::string loggerName();

    void testLog();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> m_logger;
};

#endif //LIBCLASS_H
```

*libclass.cpp*

```
#include "libclass.h"

const std::string myLoggerName = "lib_logger";

LibClass::LibClass()
{
    m_logger = spdlog::get(myLoggerName);
}

LibClass::~LibClass()
{ }

std::string LibClass::loggerName()
{
    return myLoggerName;
}

void LibClass::testLog()
{
    m_logger->info("Log from library");
}
```

**The application**

*main.cpp*

```
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <applib/libclass.h>

void logtest()
{
    auto logger = spdlog::get("app_logger");
    logger->info("Log from application");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // create loggers
    auto appLogger = spdlog::stdout_logger_mt("app_logger");
    auto libLogger = spdlog::stdout_logger_mt(LibClass::loggerName());

    // log from app
    logtest();

    // log from lib
    LibClass lc;
    lc.testLog();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Spdlog uses a singleton registry for keeping track of available loggers. You get [one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373061/what-happens-to-global-and-static-variables-in-a-shared-library-when-it-is-dynam) of that registry per dll and exe though.

When you create the logger in the exe, it is added to the exe's registry but not the dlls. When you use `spdlog::get(myLoggerName)` in your dll, you are querying the registry of the dll which does not contain the "lib_logger" and thus you are getting a null shared_ptr.

Possible solutions are: create the lib_logger in the lib instead of the exe if you are only using it in the dll anyway, or pass the logger from the exe to the dll and call `spdlog::register_logger`  with it inside the dll before calling `spdlog::get(myLoggerName)`. Then you can use the same logger from both the exe and the dll.

An example how one can register loggers across dll boundaries can be found at https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/How-to-use-spdlog-in-DLLs

Or an example using your code:

**The library**

libclass.h

```
#ifndef LIBCLASS_H
#define LIBCLASS_H

#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#  ifdef BUILD_APPLIB_SHARED
#    define APPLIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define APPLIB_EXPORT
#  endif //BUILD_APPLIB_SHARED
#else
#  define APPLIB_EXPORT
#endif // WIN32

class APPLIB_EXPORT LibClass
{
public:
  LibClass();
  ~LibClass();

  static std::string loggerName();

  void testLog();

private:
  std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> m_logger;
};

APPLIB_EXPORT void registerLogger(std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger);

#endif //LIBCLASS_H
```

libclass.cpp

```
#include "libclass.h"

const std::string myLoggerName = "lib_logger";

LibClass::LibClass()
{
  m_logger = spdlog::get(myLoggerName);
}

LibClass::~LibClass()
{ }

std::string LibClass::loggerName()
{
  return myLoggerName;
}

void LibClass::testLog()
{
  m_logger->info("Log from library");
}

APPLIB_EXPORT void registerLogger(std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger)
{
  spdlog::register_logger(logger);
}
```

**The application**
main.cpp

```
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/sinks/stdout_sinks.h>

#include <applib/libclass.h>

void logtest()
{
  auto logger = spdlog::get("app_logger");
  logger->info("Log from application");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // create loggers
  auto appLogger = spdlog::stdout_logger_mt("app_logger");
  auto libLogger = spdlog::stdout_logger_mt(LibClass::loggerName());

  registerLogger(libLogger);

  // log from app
  logtest();

  // log from lib
  LibClass lc;
  lc.testLog();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine on the [current version](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/tree/ea1a92769b270f520d335087606c5cb8944ae776) of spdlog:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp libclass.cpp  -I .
$ ./a.out 
[2015-08-24 07:29:04.502] [app_logger] [info] Log from application
[2015-08-24 07:29:04.502] [lib_logger] [info] Log from library
```

---

Same when using a shared library:

```
# CMake config:
project(TEST)
include_directories(.)
add_library(class SHARED libclass.cpp)
target_compile_options(class PUBLIC -std=c++11)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main class)
```

Results:

```
$ cmake .
$ make 
$ ldd main
    ...
    libclass.so => ...
$ ./main 
[2015-08-25 08:57:51.864] [app_logger] [info] Log from application
[2015-08-25 08:57:51.864] [lib_logger] [info] Log from library
```

Make sure that you link with a DLL runtime on Windows.

Comment: Your example is working because everything is under the same binary.
If you build libclass in a shared library and main apart linking with the shared lib, it does not work.