# How do you source a C .dll using two source files with Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

I have two source files that contain routines I want in my .dll.
I can build the .dll, but I have to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "routines1.h"
#include "routines2.h"
#include "routines1.c"
#include "routines2.c"
```

This works, but it is very ugly and I am sure it must be wrong.  I am more familiar with building libraries in Linux wherein adding files together is less problematic.  I am working in C.

Comment: Are you using an IDE (like Visual Studio or similar)? Then add the files as source files like any other source file in your project.

Comment: I tried that, but with no references to the functions, the resulting .dll is just empty.

Comment: Do you *export* the functions that the API in the DLL provides? Perhaps you should read a few tutorials about creating a DLL first?

Comment: OK, that seems to work (using __declspec( dllimport )  ).  (Not many tutorials using C.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358641 for a discussion of __declspec(dllimport) and __declspec(dllexport). Classes or functions, c++ or c, the directive works the just the same.