# Shared errno variable between library (dll) and application

Tags: c, windows, errno

I'm working with a library (linked shared, using dll/so) written in C which sets the `errno` variable if errors occurs. This library has got a function which prints the error information and the errno number on terminal/command line. My program that uses this library is written in C++.

I've made the following observation in Windows (Visual Studio 2010): If there was an error for example and then I set the `errno` to `0` after it, the printing function gets the old errno and prints that. I set it directly: `errno = 0;`.
As I'm developing under Linux and Windows I tested it on both: In Linux it works as expected means the printing function will print `0` for the `errno` value where as in Windows the old `errno` is used.
Further it is just a single thread application.

**So my question is:**
Are there two global `errno` variables one for my library (dll) and one for my application in Windows? If so is it because my program is written in C++ and the library in C using a different runtime?

I already read the documentation of [MSDN about errno](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1(v=vs.100).aspx) but can't find any informations that helps.
In the Linux [manpage about errno](https://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) is written:

> errno is thread-local; setting it in one thread does not affect its value in any other thread.

But as I said I have just one thread and in Linux it works.

**Edit #1:**
I've read [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374253/8051589) which states:

> Where it gets complicated is when you have `extern` global variables. Here, Windows and Unix-like systems are completely different
>
> In the case of Windows (.exe and .dll), the `extern` global variables are not part of the exported symbols. In other words, different modules are in no way aware of global variables defined in other modules. This means that you will get linker errors if you try, for example, to create an executable that is supposed to use an `extern` variable defined in a DLL, because this is not allowed. You would need to provide an object file (or static library) with a definition of that `extern` variable and link it statically with both the executable and the DLL, resulting in two distinct global variables (one belonging to the executable and one belonging to the DLL).

But there isn't anything statically linked?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thank you didn't found that... I will take a look on it and reply.

Comment: The question itself isn't a perfect duplicate, but the answer should definitely help you understand what's happening I think.

Comment: What the linked answer is basically saying, is that on Windows global variables are simply not shared between executables and DLLs. Each executable, and each DLL, will have their *own* copy of global variables, like `errno`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Ok got that.