# where and when the `REGISTER_SOLVER_CLASS(SGD);` is called and executed for caffe?

Tags: c++, caffe

I am interested in reading caffe source code. Now I am confused that where and when the `REGISTER_SOLVER_CLASS(SGD);`[here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp#L350) is called and executed when training a model?
anyone can give some advises? thank you very much~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in `REGISTER_SOLVER_CLASS` macro definition, in [solver_factory.hpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/solver_factory.hpp#L126), Caffe creates static global objects for the solvers. They are initialized when the library loads. See this [question + answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373061/what-happens-to-global-and-static-variables-in-a-shared-library-when-it-is-dynam) for the full details and Windows / UNIX differences.

Comment: @AndrewGong : Compiling caffe creates a static library (.a on Linux, .lib on Windows) and a dynamic library (.so on Linux, .dll on Windows). I didn't understand your comment, could you please elaborate?

Comment: nothing, and I have deleted the latest commit. your answer is good, thank you!