# Global variables and dynamic libraries using C in Mac

Tags: c, shared-libraries, shared-memory

I'm trying to understand how extern variables work when using dynamic linking and dynamic loading of shared libraries, and whether or not a large codebase that I've inherited could have problems in it. Unfortunately I cannot share code from this codebase, and wish to figure out if there's a specific issue here. I would like to know if a variable that is part of a shared library can be mutated from multiple processes that dynamically loads the shared library.

This is the main.c file.

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    while(1){
        printf("Value = %d\n", global);
        foo();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the foo.c file.

```
// foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int global = 0;

void foo(void)
{
    global = global + 1;
    sleep(1);
}
```

and this is the foo.h file.

```
// foo.h
#ifndef foo_h__
#define foo_h__

extern void foo(void);
extern int global;

#endif  // foo_h__
```

This is the Makefile for compiling this program.

```
# Makefile

all: main

main:
    gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic foo.c
    gcc -shared -o libfoo.dylib foo.o
    gcc -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo -L.
```

Since the `global` variable has an extern definition, and since a shared library is created, I was expecting that code would break when run across multiple processes. However, if I open two terminals and run `./test` in both of them simultaneously, the counter increments independently and correctly (no common shared memory). I'm glad this is how it works, but I'm curious if there's a way to break this? Reading through these answers [1-2], I thought that the shared libraries memory was loaded just once into the virtual memory space and I was under the assumption that the above code would not work, i.e. when starting the second process the first process would reset back to zero. How do I force this code above to increment the value in the same memory address in different processes? Is this possible at all?

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374253/5451769

[2] https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/244666

Comment: Most compilation models distinguish between writable and nonwritable memory.  When a shared library is shared between multiple processes, they all share a single copy of the shared library's nonwritable memory (code and constant data), but they each get their own copy of the library's writable data.  Needless to say, your variable `global` would be in a writable data segment, and would not be shared.

Comment: If you want two processes to share some memory, you can create a shared memory segment with the `shm*` system call(s).