# in which case, windows guarantee the static variable defined inside inline member functions are unique across modules(dll/exe)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374253/440403): 
global variable not exported will be only visible to its own module.

I am wondering what is the story for static variables defined inside a inline member function of a class, for example:

```
//cat.h

#ifdef EXPORT_ADD_
#define DLL_ __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_ __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

Class DLL_ Cat
{
public:
    static void foo()
    {
        static int i = 0;
        std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
    }
}
```

1) if cat.h is included in multiple module, say d1.dll,  d2,dll
   and Cat::foo() are called in each module
   what result will be guarantee to be get?
2)  it seems that __declspec(dllexport) and__declspec(dllimport) 
    play a important role.
    In my test,

```
Class  Cat {...} //DLL_ is removed
```

or

```
#define DLL_ //__declspec(dllimport)  comment out dllimport
```

the static variable will not be unique

I am wondering what is the Rule of thumb to deal with static variable inside inline member functions. Thanks.

Comment: Simple rule: don't do it, you are looking at a huge mess if things go wrong. Just put it in the cpp

Comment: "in which case, windows guarantee" - Don't care about that. Care about what the C++ standard guarantees.

Comment: @JesperJuhl what c++ standard guarantees ?

Comment: @camino Go look it up.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The C++ standard doesn't contemplate a concept of shared libraries, and says nothing about their behavior. The behavior at issue here is necessarily implementation-dependent.