# c++17 inline + thread_local vs thread_local

Tags: c++, c++17, inline, thread-local-storage, translation-unit

I am wondering what exactly the difference between the following two declarations is if both are written in a single header file:

```
inline thread_local MyClass obj1;  // inline with thread_local
thread_local MyClass obj2;         // no inline
```

As specified in C++17, adding inline to a variable forces all translation units to see the same address of that variable. Does this mean it's possible for `obj2` to get different address values in different translation units? What would be the situation to highlight we should use `obj1` rather than `obj2`?

Answer (score 3):

If you include this header file in multiple compilation units, you will get multiple definitions of `obj2`. But `obj1` will work fine because the linker will guarantee only one definition will exist and all compilation units will use the same definition (and hence the same address).

So, your code should use `extern` for `obj2` and define it in a single compilation unit. But `inline` already does that for you for `obj1`.

> Does this mean it's possible for `obj2` to get different address values
> in different translation units?

In that particular case, no, since it won't compile. But if you add `static` to `obj2`, you will get one address per compilation unit.

> What would be the situation to highlight we should use `obj1` rather
> than `obj2`?

You should never use `obj2` like this, `obj1` is the correct way. If you want to avoid `inline`, you could use `extern` for `obj2`.

Comment: One notable caveat to this is how DLLs are initialized with their own distinct instance of global variables, including thread-local variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374253/11502722

Comment: `If thread_local is the only storage class specifier applied to a block scope variable, static is also implied`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration