# Is linking two DLLs to the same static library and then linking both DLLs together a violation of the ODR?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, one-definition-rule

I have come across a situation in our codebase where two DLLs that link to each other, both link statically to the same static library. This results in both DLLs pulling in a separate copy of the static library when they are linked.

[image]

In this particular situation, the static library contains a class that is intended to be a singleton... But since both DLLs pull in their own copy, when DLL1 attempts to access the singleton it gets a different instance than DLL2! This is causing lots of issues with program state and initialization because both libraries see a different state of the program.

I understand what is happening is BAD and is a bug in the program. But is it actually in the realm of "undefined behavior"? Does this violate the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)?

What about the situation where the static library does not contain a singleton. Is it perfectly okay then, or is that still a problem? (If it violates the ODR, I assume it is still a problem.)

Comment: Put the singleton in a different dll

Comment: @drescherjm That's what I'm doing, but there's things other than just the singleton in the static library. Is it fine for those things to stay in the static library?

Comment: Even though I prefer making your static library into a DLL, I note that boost 1.68.0 headers-only form can be built into more than one DLL and it will work as expected re globals. So that suggests cleverly making the static library into a headers-only kind of a deal could also be a way out of this flavor of DLL hell.

Comment: @WilliamClements I am actually curious how this works with header only libraries... I would think you would run into the same problem.

Comment: I believe you are safe as long as you link to the same exact static library implementations. I can't answer what the standard says about this. Your singleton problem is likely because each `dll` created its own instance of a static variable.

Comment: I think this is related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373061/what-happens-to-global-and-static-variables-in-a-shared-library-when-it-is-dynam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373061/what-happens-to-global-and-static-variables-in-a-shared-library-when-it-is-dynam)

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm, the answer to that question clarifies quite a bit about how things actually work.