# Unable to access shared pointer inside shared object file

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have 3 pieces of code: main.c, main2.c and sharedlib.c

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char* sharedPtr;

int main(void)
{
    sharedPtr = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

    fprintf(stdout, "addr = 0x%x\n", sharedPtr);

    sleep(10);

    munmap(sharedPtr, 1024);

    return 0;
}
```

main2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char* sharedPtr;

int main(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "0x%x\n", (void*)sharedPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

sharedlib.c (only contains a pointer, nothing else):

```
char* sharedPtr;
```

When I launch main it prints and then sleeps for 10seconds:

```
addr = 0xb6f77000
```

During these 10 seconds I launch main2, but get this output:

```
0x0
```

Why? main.c is still running so it should have set the variable in the shared library, yet it hasn't. Why does main2 not see the value of the pointer?

How I compile:

```
gcc main.c -o main -L${PWD} -lsharedlib
gcc main2.c -o main2 -L${PWD} -lsharedlib 
gcc sharedlib.c -o libsharedlib.so -shared -fPIC
```

**EDIT**: replace that pointer by a random integer and you get the exact same result, i.e. main2 does not see the value main writes to it. main2 just prints 0. In other words it is not related to the usage of mmap.

Comment: This is not how shared libraries work. They don't share their data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to global and static variables in a shared library when it is dynamically linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373061/what-happens-to-global-and-static-variables-in-a-shared-library-when-it-is-dynam)

Comment: @DanielWalker no because, to my understanding, this page implies it should work. At least, that's how I understand it.... I am on Linux and they state: "In this case, if you do load-time linking from anywhere to a shared object file, then the global variables are shared, i.e., linked together as one."

Comment: @tkausl OK so what is the solution? Note that replacing the pointer with a normal int leads to the same issue. This here actually implies two processes sharing a statefull library cannot reliably know the state of that library they are sharing, which sounds completely nuts to me

Comment: @ohiliouh Libraries do not have a system-wide state. How would that even work? When the programs exit do you expect the OS to modify the `.so` file to hold the state of the variables until the next program runs? Sharing state like that is what the file system is for or alternatively explicit-shared memory via `mmap` or POSIX shared memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared memory does not work that way.  When you call `mmap()`, it is the *memory that mmap()'s returned pointer is pointing to* that is part of a shared-memory region, not the pointer itself; i.e. the pointer-variable `sharedPtr` is still in the (private/unshared) process-space of the calling process and access to the `sharedPtr` variable itself is unaffected by `mmap()`.

If you want to share a value between the two processes, you'll need to call `mmap()` (or better yet, [shmget()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html) and [shmat()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat)) in each of the processes, and place the value into the shared-memory region itself (e.g. `memcpy(sharedPtr, &myValue, sizeof(myValue))` or similar would copy the value stored in `myValue` to the first bytes of the shared-memory region, where both processes can "see" them).

As a side-note, even once you have done that, placing *pointers* into the shared memory region isn't normally a useful thing to do, since a pointer to an object in non-shared memory will not be usable outside of the process that owns the non-shared memory, and even a pointer to another location inside the shared-memory region itself may not work, since `mmap()` could return a different base-pointer in process A than it returns in process B.

Comment: I don't think your explanation here is entirely correct. Replace the pointer by a random int and you get exactly the same issue. So it is not related to the fact that I am using mmap.

Comment: @ohiliouh No, this answer is correct. You seem to expect that if you start two proceses both linked to the same shared library that the two processes will refer to the same instances of the variables in the library, but that's not the case. Each program will have its own copy of the variables in the shared library. Only memory mapped as shared memory with `mmap` in both processes can be shared between them.

Comment: @user17732522 Isn't the whole point of using shared libraries that they are *shared*? I'd expect this behavior for statically linked libs.

Comment: @ohiliouh No, they are shared in the sense that symbols in them are located in one file that can be used by multiple executable, rather than having a copy in each executable file. When linking a static library, the resulting executable will have a copy of all symbols of the library in itself.

Comment: @ohiliouh the point of shared libraries is that the library *file* is shared (i.e. both executables can reference the same `.so` or `.dylib` file, rather than each program having a separate copy of the file included in its executable).  That reduces the amount of disk space required, as well as the amount of RAM used (since the OS can load a single copy of the shared-library code into memory instead of one copy per executable).  However, each process still gets its own separate copy of all global variables (since otherwise processes using the same library would interfere with each other)