# What exactly is static variable behaviour in multiple linkeage of a library that contains it in C++?

Tags: c++, static, static-linking, dynamic-linking, extern

Lets imagine a scenario where I have

- an executable (A),
- a dll (B), and
- a static library (C).

Both A and B are linking C and include its header files.
Now in C exist a class:

```
class Foo {
   static const Bar& getShared(); // just defined in cpp returning _sharedVarible
   static Bar _sharedVarible; // defined in cpp
};
```

Does it mean that in this scenario I will have multiple copies of `sharedVariable` within A and B, if I call `getShared()` in each of them?

If C is also a `.dll` then would be the situation same, or as C is dll I have just one unique instance of that `sharedVariable` for both A and B?

And the last one - if both scenarios result in multiple copies of that variable is this solution where C is still `.lib`:

```
// in some header of C...
extern Bar sharedVariable;

// in some cpp of C...
sharedVariable = Bar();
```

finally providing me with just one unique instance of global `sharedVariable` for both A an B? In this last case does it matter if C is `.lib` or `.dll`?

Comment: Multiple questions in one post. Though related.

Comment: @user12002570 Yes, as I would like to hear a complex answer, as I am curious about it. I beleive this is not a simple case that everybody encounters on daily bases. I am not a junior dev myself and the senior devs I consulted this with, none of them was still able to give me a 100% sure statement what exactly is correct and provide me with some evidence (links to standard, explanation or whatever).

Comment: I found some nice answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19373061/8443797

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that in this scenario I will have multiple copies of `sharedVariable` within A and B, if I call `getShared()` in each of them?

Yes: this is one area where Windows DLLs greatly differ from UNIX shared libraries. A DLL is pretty much self contained and `getShared()` in `A` "knows nothing" about anything in `B`.

> If C is also a .dll then would be the situation same, or as C is dll I have just one unique instance of that `sharedVariable` for both A and B?

The latter. Calls from A or B will resolve to `getShared()` defined in C and will return the same address of `sharedVariable` contained within `C.DLL`.