# DLL in multiple processes

Tags: dll, shared-libraries

I have a `dll`, which is loaded by the couple of processes. In that `DLL` source code I have an instance of global variable. Will this global variable be the same in all loaded processes ? Or will it be as the unique variable in each process ?

Comment: Only the code is shared between processes.

Comment: Pretty sure it'd be unique to each process.

Comment: Normally it will be unique, though there are ways of making it shared. In Win16 they are shared though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17700531/11683

Comment: Each process should have its own copy of the variable. But you can make sure of that with a small test program that shouln't take more than 5 minutes to write.

Comment: @Bathsheba - language is irrelevant, it is *operating system* which matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be unique to each process, unless (i) you've written explicit code to share inter-process or (ii) are still using a 16 bit dll.