# In Windows, is it possible to grant another process access to a section of your own process's memory?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, process, ipc

I know that the reverse is possible (use VirtualAllocEx to gain temporary access to another process's memory), but is there a Win32 function that gives a process the ability to grant another process temporary access to a section of its own memory?

Comment: If I'm guessing your meaning correctly, the answer is no.  The best you can do is to copy the data from your memory into the memory of the target process using WriteProcessMemory.  (Well, on second thoughts I suppose you *could* inject calls to CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile into the target process.  But that's unlikely to be a good idea.)

Comment: I've voted to close because your comments indicate that you are asking something other than is stated in the question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Hmph. I would have thought that there would be an easy way to do something as simple as grant another process access to your own memory. On a separate note, how is it possible to _inject_ a function call into another process?

Comment: Well, there is, of course - Scott's answer.  Windows is designed on the assumption that processes that want to interact with one another will cooperate to do so.  There *are* functions for unilateral interaction, but they are designed only for troubleshooting/debugging.  In other words, you're not really supposed to be modifying the behaviour of another process like that - some operating systems will not allow you to do so at all, Windows does permit it but since you're outside the design specs you'll have to go the long way around.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using injection in your use-case.  But if you're curious, look up CreateRemoteThread in MSDN and/or [search for it here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CreateRemoteThread).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing memory between two processes (C, Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200998/sharing-memory-between-two-processes-c-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Windows processes can share memory. See CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile. The processes each use the same name to create or access the shared region.

Comment: I looked them up, but they don't give me the functionality I need.  I need the level of cooperation required not to exceed simply giving the receiving application a pointer.  Thanks, though.  It would have worked if they had provided a function that would map the memory to the address space of _another_ process.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. MapViewOfFile does map the memory to the caller's address space. This works for two cooperating processes that both are coded using the same memory space name.

Comment: I need to be able to map memory to the address space of a totally unrelated process, with the level of interaction not extending beyond the passing of a pointer.

Comment: @SourceX Requirements need to appear in the question. If you want to map memory into multiple processes there is exactly one option available. This is it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there any way to map the memory to the address space of another process?

Comment: My previous comment answers that. I don't know why you can't accept what multiple people have told you

Answer (score 1):

So you want Process B to be able to read or write existing memory in Process A?

In that case, all you need to do is give Process B the address in Process A's address space (e.g. send it across from Process A as a parameter in a message). Then as long as Process B has the correct access permissions it can simply use `ReadProcessMemory` or `WriteProcessMemory`.

Comment: Good answer, but it won't work for my situation.  I'm trying to find a way to pass text directly to/from a Scintilla edit control.  As far as I can tell, Scintilla doesn't use `ReadProcessMemory` or `WriteProcessMemory`—it uses its own message system (it immediately crashes if I specify my own pointer directly).  I currently use `VirtualAllocEx` as a workaround, but it has the limitation of not being able to work with administrator windows, which is necessary for it to work in all cases. It's why I need the level of cooperation not to exceed passing a pointer—it is all I can do.

Comment: Basically, what I'm looking for is a function that would allow another process to use a specific portion of my process's memory as if it were its own, with no other strings (except perhaps for those already stored in the memory :) ) attached.  Is this possible?

Comment: @SourceX Your stated goal ("allow another process to use a specific portion of my process's memory as if it were its own") is what `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory` are for. But now that you've explained more this sounds like more of an XY problem. To read directly out of an edit control (either in- or out-of-process) would only work if the data were all in one contiguous chunk and you knew what the address was. It's extremely unlikely the edit control will work like that.

Comment: This is how my algorithm for getting text from the control works right now:

1) I send a message to the control to determine the required buffer size.
2) I allocate a chunk of memory that size from the control's process's memory using `VirualAllocEx`.
3) I send a message to the control telling it to copy the desired text to the buffer I just allocated.
4) I copy the text from the control buffer into my own.
5) I free the buffer I previously allocated using `VirtualFreeEx`.

Comment: I want it to be this:

1) I send a message to the control to determine the required buffer size.
2) I allocate a chunk of my own memory and give the control permission to access it using `VirtualGrant` (this is a placeholder name for the function I'm looking for).
3) I send a message to the control telling it to copy the desired text to the memory I just allocated.
4) I revoke access to the memory using `VirtualRevoke` (another placeholder name).
5) I copy the text I just retrieved to another buffer (if required).

This should help anyone trying to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Your magical `VirtualGrant` function is exactly the behaviour you get now if you give the other process the local address and it uses `ReadProcessMemory` to read from it. Or use mapped memory like @ScottMcP-MVP suggests. There are ways of doing what you want already without making up new ones.

Comment: @SourceX: the approach you describe as "how my algorithm ... works right now" sounds like it does exactly what you need.  The approach you're suggesting, even if it were possible, has no obvious advantages.  In particular, it is very unlikely to make any difference to the problem you allude to above ("administrator windows").  (If you want advice about that, post a new question with more detail, or email me directly using the address shown in my profile.)