# Can a process free the memory of another process?

Tags: process, operating-system

Can a process intentionally / unintentionally read/rewrite the memory used by another process? How could this be achieved?

Comment: Not usually - unless process A allows process B to share it's memory using something like memory mapped files - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200998/sharing-memory-between-two-processes-c-windows

Comment: This will be a serious security problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some operating systems allow privileged processes to schedule software interrupts for another process. You allocate a block of memory in the system space, write your code to modify the other process into the block of memory (ensuring the block gets freed), then schedule the software interrupt for the other process to execute this block of code.